# Creating a blog from scratch but insert into in a function does not work with form

Tags: php

a newbie in PHP here.
I am currently creating a blog from scratch.  I have a problem with INSERT INTO.  Here is my code.  The function for the query INSERT INTO does not seem to populate the table.
SQL injection security will be worked on later.

**dbconnection.php**

```
 <?php
 /* Connexion au serveur de la base de donnees */
   $conn=mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_MDP );
   if (!$conn){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }else{
/* Connexion a la base de donnees */
$dbselect=mysqli_select_db( $conn, DB_SELECT );
    if (!$dbselect){
        echo "Cannot select database" ;
    }
}

 ?>
```

This is the page which contains the function for the query.
**article.sql.php**

```
// INSERT
function insertArticle( $c ){
$qryInsertArt = 'INSERT INTO articles
        VALUES ( 
               \''.$TitreArticle.'\',
            \''.$AuteurArticle.'\',
            \''.$ContenuArticle.'\'
                  )';
$result = mysqli_query (  $qryInsertArt );
return ($result);
```

}

And this is my form:
**articleform.php**

```
<h2>Articles</h2>
<form action="index.php?page=articles&action=" method="post">

<table class="admin_form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <?php $insertA = selectArticles($conn); ?>

<tr>
    <td width="30%"><label for="TitreArticle">Titre</label></td>
    <td><input id="TitreArticle" type="text" name="TitreArticle" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])){echo $_POST['TitreArticle'];} ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%"><label for="AuteurArticle">Auteur</label></td>
    <td><input id="AuteurArticle" type="text" name="AuteurArticle" value="<?php   if(isset($_POST['AuteurArticle'])){echo $_POST['AuteurArticle'];} ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><label for="ContenuArticle">Contenu de l'article</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="ContenuArticle" name="ContenuArticle"><?php if(isset($_POST['ContenuArticle'])){echo $_POST['ContenuArticle'];} ?></textarea></td>

</tr>
<tr>    
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn" href="index.php">Annuler</a>
        <input type="submit"  value="Envoyer" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One major issue is variable scope; in your function `insertArticle`, none of the variables are defined, so there's nothing to insert. You should also be checking the return value of all your database calls, to see if there was a problem, so you can handle it appropriately - `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` will show exactly what goes wrong when you run a query.

Comment: What tutorial you are learning from?

Comment: @andrewsi: the OP is using the `mysqli` library.

Comment: Swissed: you should be using _parameterisation_ here, rather than injecting insert values manually. You'll probably have a SQL injection hole with this code.

Comment: @halfer - So he is. It's clearly too early for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax of the mysqli_connect is this:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

You need to pass the db name also in this function.

`mysqli_select_db` is used the change the db after connection created.

And in the INSERT query from where you are getting these variables:

```
$TitreArticle
$AuteurArticle
$ContenuArticle
```

Check properly are these have values or not.